# Hermitian Matrix to a Power

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, adjoint-operators, hermitian-matrices

When a matrix is Hermitian. Prove that when the matrix is powered to an integer, an even integer is the only case that produces a Hermitian and Positive semidefinite matrix.

if $M = M^{H}$ then $M^{e}=(M^{e})^{H}$ and $v^{T}M^{e}v \geq0$?

My Attempt:

To prove it's hermitian:
(M$\times$M...M)$^{H}=(M^{H}$$\times$$M^{H}...M^{H})=(M^{H})^{n}$

Comment: are you sure this is the full question statement?

Comment: Yes, we know the matrix is Hermitian we want to prove that when it is raised to the power of an even integer the conditions are valid

Comment: *is the only case*? are you sure? Also include what you have tried

Comment: When a matrix raised to any integer it's still Hermitian. What I am puzzled with is how  being semidefinite is affected by even integer exponent

Comment: To begin with, $iI_{n}$ is not Hermitian. Our assumption is that our matrix is Hermitian. How do I put it in mathematical form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $M$ is Hermitian, then it is unitarily diagonalizable.

$$M=UDU^H$$

and $D$ consists of real eigenvalues along the diagonal and $0$ elsewhere and $U$ is unitary.

If $e$ is an even number, then

$$M^e=UD^eU^H$$

where $D^e$ will consists of nonnegative diagonal entries.

However, for an odd number, $p$, $D^p$ might consists of some negative numbers.

However, one should be cautious. Even if $p$ is odd, it is possible that for some $M$, $M^e$ is positive semidefinite, take the zero matrix or the identity matrix for example.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer makes sense. It can be also solved by n = e/2, and show the whole equation goes to the power of 2.